# Raster in Spyder about save, export etc

Tags: python, spyder, raster, gdal, rasterio

I have a problem about with Spyder. I want to saving the raster output to created with rasterio module. But where is the Created output in Spyder? I must find Because I cant export the raster
Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I searching the python code .